# React PHP with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, reactphp

I'm using Laravel 4 and as I was going through React PHP , wandering if there is any way to use React PHP with Laravel.

Is there any example to start with React PHP with Laravel ? or any suggestion to use it with Laravel ?

Comment: Are you saying you want react to play webserver, and run laravel in that webserver? A little bit of insight in what you hope to gain with this might help.

Comment: i came across React Php that used for Non-Blocking IO in php . The thing is , i want to implement Non-blocking IO in Laravel as node.js do. how can i do that ?

Comment: did the tutorial help? its an interesting play but it uses emberjs too so i was a bit turn off by it.

Comment: nop,I"ve started with it but same problem ..too much emberjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked for a place to start or examples of React with Laravel, you should check out this link. Christopher Pitt uses React to create a real time chat using Laravel (and EmberJS).

https://medium.com/laravel-4/eaa550829538